# MySQL: Count Columns Per Row

Tags: mysql, count

I just want to know if counting columns is possible as you're counting rows without calling each column name. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(FOUND COLUMNS) AS counted FROM table WHERE a_value EXISTS IN COLUMNS

/* 

The same as this specified one. This is working but I'm 
looking for another approach without calling each column name.

SELECT (IF(col1="Y",1,0) + IF(col2="Y",1,0)) as counted FROM table

*/
```

Which I wish will throw results per row like:

```
|  counted  |
|-----------|
|     2     |
|     1     |
|     0     |
```

**IS THAT POSSIBLE?** If yes, how?

Comment: Could you give more details like give table structure , sample data

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy I did some updates to the post. Is it okay now or still lack of info? :>

Comment: Yea lack of info. You did not provide structure only give result you wanted

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy Do I still need to add that? The running example is commented already right there.

Comment: u can count the number of columns of a specific table but why your example result gives more than one rows??

Comment: @Vanojx1 Mm... I'm kinda lost at it now. Don't know now how to deliver my question. * cries in the corner *

Comment: The number of columns in a query result is fixed for all rows by the query, not 'random'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think he want to count collumns where a certain value appear, and per row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
```

Try this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for that

**THE SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers`( `col1` INT, `col2` INT, `col3` INT, `col4` INT ); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '6'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '9'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('4', '1', '0', '2'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('9', '5', '1', '3'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('5', '0', '6', '4'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('2', '0', '1', '6'); 
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('8', '5', '6', '7');
```

**COUNT THE VALUE '0' OF EACH ROW**

```
SELECT (c1+c2+c3+c4) AS counted FROM 
(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN col1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c1,
CASE WHEN col2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c2,
CASE WHEN col3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c3,
CASE WHEN col4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c4
FROM numbers
) AS temp_count
```

> /*RESULT*/
>
> ### counted
>
> ```
>     3
>     2
>     1
>     0
>     1
>     1
>     0
> ```

**COUNT THE VALUE '7' OF EACH ROW**

```
SELECT (c1+c2+c3+c4) AS counted FROM 
(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN col1 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c1,
CASE WHEN col2 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c2,
CASE WHEN col3 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c3,
CASE WHEN col4 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c4
FROM numbers
) AS temp_count
```

So you must replace the value of `col1 = 7`,`col2 = 7`,`col3 = 7`,`col4 = 7`, if you want check the others value.

Comment: Great, your query throws the desired result. But if it's possible, I don't want to call each column's name... I'm thinking if I could just call all the columns in a single syntax like `CASE WHEN (ALL_COLUMNS) = 7 ...` hmm...

Comment: you can't i think, i will search about it in one hour

Comment: I guess you're right. That's what I'm also thinking yesterday xD

Comment: so you can upvote or acept the answer or both, because there is no way to do it like `CASE WHEN (ALL_COLUMNS) = 7 ...`

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. If you will answer like "No, it's not possible.... etc.. etc..." and will provide some links that will prove your answer then I would love to accept it.... but give me few more time and I'll give up searching for answers, then I'll accept your answer :)